# Need Excel Formula related to Evaluation/Summation

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet like below:

```
Estimated Cost     130
Discount (%)        10
------------------------
Desired Cost       117


Item    Quanity    Rate Min.    Rate Max.    Rate    Total(Quanity*Rate)
Wood    10         2.00         4.00         4.00    40.00
Sand    10         5.00         8.00         6.00    60.00
Cement  10         3.00         5.00         4.00    40.00
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                      Actual Cost    140
```

Here column Rate should be adjusted such that the Actual Cost becomes 117. Note that the adjusted Rate value should not be less than Rate Min. and should not be greater than Rate Max. Is there any formula or piece of code to handle this. Also the values should be accurate to 2 decimal places and should not exceed 2 decimal places. I am new to Excel, any help would highly be appreciated.

Comment: sorry, couldn't understand properly.

Comment: @hrehman, consider about using [**Solver**](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/define-and-solve-a-problem-by-using-solver-HP010342416.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Should the rates of the items be discounted by the same amount?  If yes, just add two columns (Adjusted Rate and Adjusted Total) to your sheet.

```
Adjusted Rate = Actual Cost / Desired Cost * Rate.  
Adjusted Cost = Adjusted Rate  * Quantity
```

If the discount rate can be different per item, then the sum gets complex and has multiple correct answers (eg, you could discount Wood only to make up the difference, or split it between Wood and Sand, leaving cement at its original rate).

As far as the decimal places, the best option is to let all the calculations use as many decimal places as they need, but round off the displayed total to two decimals.  This gives the greatest accuracy, regardless of the desired precision.

Comment: Discount rate can be same per item. Only concern is there is should be a constraint of 2 decimal places in every cell i.e. no value can go beyond 2 decimal places even in calculation. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I would be very surprised if you want the _actual_ calculation to be restricted to 2dp.  It is trivial to change the display, so you (and your bosses etc) only ever **see** two decimal places.  Do this by right clicking in the sheet and select Format Cells/Number.

Comment: NB: I haven't dealt with the 'must be > MinRate' and 'must be < MaxRate' conditions. This is because I wasn't sure about whether the change in rate could be different for individual items.  There may be cases where the rate discount will need to be different in order to keep the rates in the correct zone.  As I said, however, this increases complexity (which is why i answered the easier question).  You'll need to do what-if analysis, and as simoco suggests, this is where the Solver add-in becomes useful.